# Elasticsearch Searching multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-5, inverted-index

I know elasticsearch provides search across multiple indices. But I wonder how it's Inverted Index is constructed(populated) to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens at backend is elasticsearch uses wildcard search for that based on conditions you searched for.
you can have more detailed information over this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) and [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html).

About documents, you are getting at first es just send you 10 docs to fasten search. for more details [visit this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) I have also put an example below.

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this in you second link:  "By not limiting our search to a particular index or type, we have searched across all documents in the cluster. Elasticsearch forwarded the search request in parallel to a primary or replica of every shard in the cluster, gathered the results to select the overall top 10, and returned them to us."  This is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: if you are looking for to get more result you need to define size in your search let me add that in my answer so you can have better understanding.

Comment: I knew it, My doubt is basically this:
Will it stores the index of each "term" in One single Inverted Index itself?  Or Will it stores Inverted Index separately for all indices and gather all the results when a multi-index query comes?
I got to understand that it is the second way from the link. :)